# Should I maintain one or two unique IDs for a dual-role user?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, relational-database

Apologies if I wasn't able to describe the problem accurately in the title. My scenario is as follows.

My site operates as a platform to connect vendors and buyers. Vendors list down the goods/services they have available and buyers are able to purchase goods/services from them.

New buyer (user) registration is straightforward in that their information gets stored in `users` tables (`users, user_profile, user_history` etc.) tied together with a unique `user_id`. What I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around now is that I require vendors to register as well (for verification purposes,) and that vendors can also be buyers.

My `users` table is like so:

```
user_id  <--- primary key
name
email
...
```

and a related table may look like so:

```
transaction_id
user_id  <--- foreign key
date
amount
...
```

My initial thought for the `vendors` table:

```
vendor_id   <--- primary key
user_id  <--- foreign key
vending_name
registration_number
...
```

and a related table:

```
product_id
vendor_id  <--- foreign key
name
price
...
```

My question is, would it be best to have this `vendor_id` to link up all the vendor-related tables or should I stick with using the `user_id` for everything?

Thanks.

Comment: A 'user' can have the 'role' `vendor` and/or the 'role' `buyer`? Each of these 'roles' have different sets of criteria that must be met before the role is active? Any 'activity' by a 'user' is against a particular 'role'? Does that make sense? And could you audit trail it? It is certainly 'auditable' to the user even if not against a particular 'role'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Think of this scenario, could a user ever become a vendor (or vice versa?) if so then it's best to plan your data models around a base user and add attributes or flags (in a separate table or field). This way, you can add/remove privileges.

i.e. Have a separate tables called "flags" "flagmappings"

```
//flags
flag_name <--- 'Vendor', 'User'

//flagmappings
user_id  <--- foreign key
flag_id  <--- foreign key
```

This structure gives you a few benefits:

- For any given user you can search flagmappings and then determine what privileges a user might have.
- All your login/authentication logic is the same for all users/vendors (i.e. you don't have to split/special case different tables if it's a vendor or a user, all the base information is in the same place).
- If a user needs to become a vendor or vice versa you simply add that flag to the user.
- If you need to create yet another type of user (i.e. administrator, manager, etc.) it's just another entry in the flag table.

Comment: I already have a privileges table but I think I can repurpose it a bit as per your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just stick with the users table for everything (as long as you don't have a gazillion vendor-specific fields). It just makes things cleaner. Then, you might have a 'is_vendor' field in the users table.

Or if you want to go even more sophisticated, you could implement roles with something like this:

```
users Table
id
firstname
etc...

groups Table
id
title
etc.

user_groups Table
user_id
group_id
```

Personally, I would go with the second option because it allows for more role-based permissions, such as admin, editor, moderator, buyer, seller, super-buyer, super-seller, etc.